# Prometheus query to visualize "Cluster Node CPU Utilization" - many-to-many matching not allowed

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager, prometheus-operator

I am trying to query the Cluster Node CPU Utilization for my Kubernetes cluster using the prometheus. I am using the following query

```
sum by (kubernetes_node) (rate(node_cpu_seconds_total{mode!~"idle|wait|iowait"}[5m])) / on (kubernetes_node) label_join(machine_cpu_cores, "kubernetes_node", "", "kubernetes_io_hostname") * 100 > 80
```

But I get the following error:

> Error executing query: found duplicate series for the match group {} on the right hand-side of the operation: [{name="machine_cpu_cores", boot_id="", endpoint="https-metrics", instance="", job="kubelet", machine_id="", metrics_path="/metrics/cadvisor", namespace="kube-system", node="aks-oi--vmss000002", service="-kube-prometheus-sta-kubelet", system_uuid=""}, {name="machine_cpu_cores", boot_id="", endpoint="https-metrics", instance="", job="kubelet", machine_id="", metrics_path="/metrics/cadvisor", namespace="kube-system", node="aks-defaultnp01--vmss000004", service="-kube-prometheus-sta-kubelet", system_uuid=""}];many-to-many matching not allowed: matching labels must be unique on one side

Could someone please help me with this? I am very new to prometheus queries and I greatly appreciate your help on this :)

Thank You!

Comment: Well, many to many for operations (`/` here) is not allowed in Prometheus. If I understand what you are trying to do correctly - you need to wrap both dividend ((?) what is divided) and divider with `sum by (kubernetes_node)`

Comment: Hi @markalex, could you help me out with an example on this? I am new to the `promql`. Thank You!

Comment: Would it look like this? `sum by (kubernetes_node) ( sum by (kubernetes_node) (rate(node_cpu_seconds_total{mode!~"idle|wait|iowait"}[5m])) / on (kubernetes_node) label_join( sum by (kubernetes_node) (machine_cpu_cores), "kubernetes_node", "", "kubernetes_io_hostname" ) * 100 > 80 )` @markalex But this is producing "empty query result"

Comment: I thought of something like `sum by (kubernetes_node) (rate(node_cpu_seconds_total{mode!~"idle|wait|iowait"}[5m])) / sum by (kubernetes_node) (label_join(machine_cpu_cores, "kubernetes_node", "", "kubernetes_io_hostname"))`

Comment: Hi @markalex thank you, this is working. my only question is, how can I filter out node cpu > 80% with this query?

Comment: I don't know what those metrics are exactly. I'd start with your initial attempt of `<current query> * 100 > 80`.

Comment: gives me empty result list again. Any idea how can I filter out nodes that has exceeded the 80% of cpu? @markalex

Comment: So maybe none are exceeding 80%?

Comment: Tried with a different number as well, like `20` but still the same :(

Comment: Hi @markalex it worked as I checked node cpu is not more than 12%